# Auto-connecting 4G/LTE on startup (with USB modem)

Tags: networking, usb-modem, huawei, 4g

I have a Huawei E3372 modem which works just fine - it shows up in the settings and I can easily connect to the network, but I'm trying to set up a machine that ideally would boot up automatically when powered on and connect by itself. This could be done once during startup or via some continuous checking, I don't mind creating a script that does this but I'm not sure how to interface with the modem.

How could I approach that?

EDIT

Looks like the `mmcli` command is what I'm looking for. I'm not yet sure how to use it but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Network manager has a cli: `nmcli`.

If the modem is recognized by the network manager (in my case it is) then its connection UUID will show up when running:

`nmcli connection show`

Then, it can be simply enabled with:

`nmcli connection up <connection-uuid>`

That's it. The modem will connect to the cellular network and the corresponding interface will be automatically configured.